# Deploy in an iPad as iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cydia

I am developing one application for iPad and iPhone. The problem is that I only have one iPad. I need to develop in a physical device cause I have some libraries inside the project that only works in device.
Are there any way to deploy in my iPad as an iPhone to check if the application code is working fine?
I have a jailbroken device.

Thanks!!

Comment: Just remove the reference to the iPad xib/storyboard in the summary tab.

Comment: http://www.ubergizmo.com/2012/10/its-legal-to-jailbreak-your-iphone-but-not-an-ipad/ you may be interested in this. ( No location listed in your profile... I assume US ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode select your target and then the Summary tab. Change the Devices value from Universal to iPhone. Now build and run your app on your iPad. It will run in iPhone compatibility mode on the iPad.

Don't forget to put that option back to Universal before shipping the app to Apple.

One limitation is you can't test to see if your app works on the 4" devices. The iPhone compatibility mode only works in 3.5" mode.